# Prevent c++ istream from locking when calling 'get' and 'peek'

Tags: c++, performance, locking, istream

I'm currently reading a text file in c++ using an istream, and I noticed that there's significant overhead from the istream locking the file after every read (istream get and peek methods, specifically).

If I understand correctly, this locking occurs for thread safety, but I'm only planning on using a single thread, so it feels unnecessary.

Is there any way to prevent this thread locking when reading from the istream?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: I attached a VTune results image containing an overview of where the time is being spent.

[image: VTune image of all the lock_file sections]

Comment: @Galik, thanks, I'll try that out

Comment: @Galik, that only works with standard streams, not with istream

Comment: I am unaware of a flag or `#define` you can use to disable this.  The standard mandates that the streams be thread safe so I'm not sure if would be to disable that.

Comment: @NathanOliver, hmm, do you know of any similar alternative to istream that could be used instead then that is less strict in thread safety?

Comment: There are the C IO functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not supported, there appear to be some hacker-y ways of doing this:

for char = in.get(), or in.get(char&), use [std::sbumpc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/sbumpc/).

for char = in.peek(), use [std::sgetc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/sgetc/).

So:

```
// Old:
char c = in.get();
char p = in.peek();

// New:
char c = in.rdbuf()->sbumpc();
char p = in.rdbuf()->sgetc();
```

Note that these methods will not be thread safe, and will not automatically detect eof. Only use when performance is critical, and be aware of checks yourself.